# jquery drag and drop - dragging between two list, how to delete selected list in drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have one problem with jQuery Ui drag & drop functionality.

I need to delete selected `<li>` in drop list

My code:

```
$( "#sortable-left, #sortable-right" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();

$("#sortable-right").on("click", "li a", function () {
$(".mdm-right-sortable li").remove();
});
```

You can view the full code here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8AEw/3/)

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: did u tried anything so far? I Mean any Fiddle to show?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee yeah he did make a try.. But anyway the question seems kind of unclear.

Comment: Yes i have tried to delete selected list(li) in drop.

Comment: @user3839302 Reproduce your issue here.. www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: How to add my code to jsfiddle?

Comment: See my code: http://jsfiddle.net/n8AEw/3/

Comment: @user3839302 hi, i cleaned up your fiddle. the top right panel is jsfiddle is dedicated for css. You don't have to dump the entire code of `jQuery ui` in the js section, you can find it from few query version in frameworks, or if a resource you're using is unavailable in frameworks, you can add it by entering an online link to it using the `external resources` option. Hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the clicked `<li>` using `this` keyword.

Change

```
$("#sortable-right").on("click", "li", function () {
     $(".mdm-right-sortable li").remove();
 });
```

to

```
$("#sortable-right").on("click", "li", function () {
     $(this).remove();
 });
```

[UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8AEw/4/)

**Update:** *(As per comments)*

You can remove the `<li>` by clicking the icon in using `closest()`, as shown below:

```
$("#sortable-right").on("click", "li a", function () {
     $(this).closest('li').remove();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for updated. pls drag more than 2 from "Listed Responsibilities" in to "Selected items". after that click the red box in "Selected items". it will delete all list(li). this is the issue. i need to delete selected particular list only. is this possible. http://jsfiddle.net/n8AEw/5/  thanks

Comment: @user3839302 check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n8AEw/6/). Instead of clarifying in comments, please update the question properly with the exact requirements so that people will understand and value your question and up vote it. accept the answer if it helped...

Comment: Thanks. it working fine. one more help. if i delete any of the list in "Selected items", the deleted list need be to add in "Listed Responsibilities" is this possible

Comment: Sorry, this is a `Q&A` site. Not were people do the coding for you until the requirements are satisfied. This question is answered, so accept it if it solved the question above, and If you are facing further trouble with the output, try to fix it, if you're unable to - post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69" alt="your image or text is here: drag it in to the box :">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need delete option. is this possible